# Why did the author warn 'Don't do it!' on evaluating the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{\sin ^4 x}$ this way?

Tags: limits

This is taken from *Differential Calculus* by Amit M Agarwal:

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{\sin ^4 x}$$

The question is quite easy using trigonometric identity viz. $1-\cos x = 2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$ and then using $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}= 1\,.$ The answer is $\frac{1}{8}\,.$

However, after evaluating the limit, the author cautioned as

> ## Don't do it!
>
> \begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{\sin ^4 x} & =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot x^2\right)}{x^4}\\ &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{x^4}\qquad \left(\textrm{As}\, \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}= \frac{1}{2} \right)\\&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x^2}{4}}{\frac{x^4}{16}\times 16}\\&= \frac{1}{8}\qquad \textrm{is wrong although the answer may be correct}\,.\end{align}

Where is the 'wrong' in the evaluation?

## Edit:

> - [...] the limit as $x\to 0$ is taken for a subexpression. That's generally invalid.
> - We can't evaluate a limit inside a limit like that.
> - While evaluating limit of a complicated expression one should not replace a sub-expression by its limit and continue with further calculations.

Now, consider these limits:

$$\bullet \lim_{x \to 4} \log(2x^{3/2}- 3x^{1/2}-1)$$

my book solves this as:

$$\log\; [\lim_{x\to 4} 2 x^{3/2}- \lim_{x\to 4} 3x^{1/2} - \lim_{x\to 4} 1]= 2\log 3$$

Another one:

$$\bullet \lim_{x\to 1} \sin(2x^2- x- 1)$$

This is solved as;

$$\sin\;[\lim_{x\to 1} 2x^2 \lim_{x\to 1} x- \lim_{x\to 1} 1]= \sin 0= 0$$

The following limits are evaluated by first evaluating the limits of **sub-expressions**. Do these contradict the statement _ you can't take limit of a **sub-expression** while evaluating the limit of the whole function_?

Comment: The answer is not $1/8$. It is $1/2$.

Comment: @Watson: Typo. Sorry.

Comment: What is written before the "Don't do it!" ? I don't understand how the first equality is obtained.

Comment: What book/paper/notes did you get this from?

Comment: @Wojowu: Given the source.

Comment: @Taladris: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot x^2\right)}{x^4}/\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}$$; now have you got it?

Comment: In the step from the first to the second line, the limit as $x\to 0$ is taken for a subexpression. That's generally invalid. It's particularly insidious since often you get the correct result when you do that.

Comment: @user36790: the LHS was a completely different expression when I typed my comment. The title was also different.

Comment: @Taladris: I confessed that it was typo and that comment was 7s ahead of yours; so sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While evaluating limit of a complicated expression one should **not** replace a sub-expression by its limit and continue with further calculations. Thus the step where you replace $(1 - \cos x)/x^{2}$ by $1/2$ is not allowed.

However there are two situations where you can do such replacements:

1) If a sub-expression is connected *in additive manner* to the rest of the expression then this sub-expression can be replaced by its limit (provided the limit exists). More formally *if $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exists and is equal to $L$ then  $$\lim_{x \to a}\{f(x) \pm g(x)\} = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \pm L$$ irrespective of the fact whether $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists or not.*

2) If a sub-expression is connected *in multiplicative manner* to the rest of the expression then this sub-expression can be replaced by its limit (provided the limit exists and is **non-zero**). More formally *if $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exists and is equal to $L \neq 0$ then  $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = L\lim_{x \to a}f(x),\,\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{L}\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$$ irrespective of the fact whether $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists or not.*

These are the **only two situations** where we can replace the sub-expression ($g(x)$ in the formal versions mentioned above) with its limit ($L$).

The above theorems help us a lot in simplifying the limit evaluation of a complicated expression because in each step we can replace a sub-expression by its limit without worrying about the limit of the remaining part of the expression ($f(x)$ in the formal version) and thereby effectively reducing complicated expressions to simpler ones. Also note that by the use of these rules we can infer the existence (or non-existence) of the limit of a complicated expression (consisting of both $f(x), g(x)$) from the existence (or non-existence) of the limit of a simpler expression ($f(x)$).

**Update**: OP has raised a very interesting point (via comments) where a sub-expression might not be related to the rest of the expression via arithmetical operations $+,-,\times,/$, but rather through functional symbol. In this case we have the rule that *the order of a limit operation and the functional operation can be interchanged provided the function is continuous*. More formally *if $f$ is continuous then $$\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to a}g(x))$$* Note that in this case we *don't replace a sub-expression by its limit*, here the main operation is *interchanging the order* of applying limit operation and functional operation. The example mentioned in your comment uses the fact that the $\log$ function is continuous wherever it is defined and hence the interchange of limit operation and $\log$ operation is justified.

Comment: Thanks, sir, for posting the answer. See this limit: $$\lim_{x \to 4} \log(2x^{3/2}- 3x^{1/2}-1)$$ The limit is evaluated like this $$\log [\lim_{x\to 4} 2 x^{3/2}- \lim_{x\to 4} 3x^{1/2} - \lim_{x\to 4} 1]= 2\log 3$$ Now, is it contradicting the statement that _you can't take limit of a __sub-expression__ while evaluating the limit of the whole function_?

Comment: @user36790: Thanks for your comment. I will update my answer to handle this case.

Comment: I'll edit my question to air this matter.

Comment: @user36790: I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user36790: you may also upvote the answer if you wish.

Comment: Just noticed! `irrespective of the fact whether` $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ `exists or not.` - no, that's not true. In order to apply Fundamental Theorem, both the limits should exist. Check, this, for example: $$f(x)= \frac{x^2}{x-1}\,\,\textrm{and}\,\, g(x)= \frac{1}{x-1}$$ Then what should be the lim of $f(x)- g(x)$ as $x\to 1\;?$ You can't apply the addition rule, as neither the limit of those functions exist as $x\to 1$ i.e. $$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)- g(x)]\ne \lim_{x\to a}f(x)- \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ as the former exists and not the later.

Comment: Same is the case of the multiplication rule; in order to apply the rules, the limits of the separate functions need to exist.

Comment: @user36790: It appears that you have not read my post with due attention that it requires. I have mentioned my theorems where limit of one of the functions $g(x)$ exists and then I mention that you don't need to worry about the existence of limit of other function $f(x)$. In the examples which you give the limit of both functions does not exist and hence my rule does not apply.

Comment: @user36790: The rules which I have written are not normally available in textbooks and hence you might be a little surprised. The fundamental theorems which you mention are more commonly available in textbooks and my rules are a generalization of the fundamental theorems.

Comment: Please check the deduction of the fundamental Theorem: http://www.opensourcemath.org/books/calc1-sage/html/Fundamental_theorems_on_lim.html

Comment: @user36790: I know the proof of the fundamental theorems which you talking about and also the proof of the rules which i have mentioned in my post. Both the things are true/correct. Why do you think that the rules which i have mentioned are invalid (or perhaps contradict the fundamental theorems)?

Comment: hmm...it's only that for your rule, which is the Fundamental Theorem, to be valid, the limits of both the functions should exist and be finite, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36537/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-user36790).

Answer (score 16):

Second equality is precisely what's wrong. We can't evaluate a limit inside a limit like that. To make it clearer, let's look at another example.

Consider a limit
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{x}$$

We have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}x=0$, but we can't say $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{x}$$
Since limit on the LHS is clearly $1$ and on the RHS is clearly $0$. Even if in the case of limit in question the answer was correct (which I didn't bother to check), the way of evaluating this limit is invalid, which is why you should not do that.